# Mark duplicates in a column depending on the data in another column

Tags: google-sheets

I work in a recruitment call centre (not cold calling don't worry) and I'd like a way to highlight duplicate email addresses in one column of a google sheets spreadsheet. Basically I want them to highlight as one colour if the email is a duplicate but hasn't resulted in an interview, and highlight with another colour if the duplicate email is associated with an interview or rejection.

[Here's what I'm thinking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAkww.png)

I want the email from the "jack@gmail.com" address to be green since it is next to a "left message" notice, while the "cameron@gmail.com" should be red since it is next to a "Declined" notice.

I've already worked out the basics of using conditional statements and I'm using "=countif(A:A,A1)>1" to at least highlight the duplicates but I have no idea how to use information from column B to make a conditional.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using a COUNTIF with VLOOKUP for the Conditional Formatting. Assuming your emails start at B2 and your statuses start at C2, you could use the following Conditional Formatting rules to get your desired behaviour:

```vb
=IF(COUNTIF(B$2:B, B2) > 1, IF(VLOOKUP(B2,B$2:C,2,False) = "Left Message", True, False), False)

=IF(COUNTIF(B$2:B, B2) > 1, IF(VLOOKUP(B2,B$2:C,2,False) = "Declined", True, False), False)
```

---

#### [Here's a sample sheet I made just for you.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GgGk1ZtYwlRMb3dKCUuKmiCzDvdzbSVHYm5_7LaY_9k/edit?usp=sharing)

You can edit emails around and try it out yourself.